# FTP File Upload doesn't work - uploads empty files

Tags: file-upload, ftp, filezilla

Here's my problem. I have to edit the file of a website. The client gave me the ftp data.

When I connect everything works fine until I wanted to edit the file. When I was done editing and wanted to save it, it got replaced with an empty file on the server. I tried again several times, same results.

So then I tried writing the file on my computer and uploading it. It still uploads an empty file.

I randomly tried uploading anything, like an image, and it uploads a .jpg that's 0 bytes.

Has anyone encountered something like this before, or does anyone know what the cause may be and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Please check server Space in your server i think space is full

Comment: No sorry, that was it, you were right. The guy had some 2gb backups blocking the whole server. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Wow, it's really long time since this has been asked, but just in case someone has a similar problem...

FTP communication happens simultaneously on two separate connections, one on port 21 (control port) and one on a port >1023 (data-transfer port).
In case you obeserve a normal behaviour when connecting to and navigating on the server, but uploaded/downloaded files have no content (size of 0kB) after the transfer, then one possibility is that the data-transfer connection is blocked by the firewall, whereas the control connection isn't.

If possible, try to use passive mode for the connection on the client side, or check and open up your firewall settings.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a permissions error, or possibly your client isn't using PASV. Paste logs from your ftp client, it may have a error/warning/etc