# Can't upload a file to FTP with WScript.Shell / cmd

Tags: cmd, ftp, wsh

I've created simple HTA-page

```
<input type="button" value="Run" onclick="run();">
<script>
function run() {
 var shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
 shell.run('cmd /c ftp -i -s:D:\ftp.bat',0,true);
}
</script>
```

And on my disk D created `ftp.bat`

```
open mydomain.com
username
password
cd /public_html
mput D:\filetobeuploaded.txt
quit
```

But when I run script on the HTA-page, file is not being uploaded to FTP.

If I run my BAT-file via cmd.exe, I succesfully connect to my FTP, but after mput command I get

> 500 I won't open a connection to 111.111.111.111 <only to
>   222.222.222.222>
>
> 425 No data connection

where 222.222.222.222 is my IP

As I can understand there are two separate problems:

**1.** I can't connect with FTP if I use

`shell.run('cmd /c ftp -i -s:D:\ftp.bat',0,true);`

**2.** I can't upload a file to FTP (no data connection)

Comment: Your .bat file is an ftp script.  It is not a .BAT file.  You should consider using `ftp.exe` instead of just `ftp` for the command.  Depending on your current working directory it could see ftp.bat and think that is the ftp.exe command.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can do something on FTP for example create a directory or rename a file if I use `shell.run('cmd /c ftp.exe -s:ftp.bat',0,true)` in my HTA-file. That has resolved the first problem. But I still can't upload a file

Comment: `MPUT` is normally used for multiple files whereas `PUT` is used for a single file. Also if the file name has spaces in it, then you need to quote the file name.

Comment: Oh, it's Firewall. Ok, another question is: can I run the command with ftp.exe without changing firewall settings? Or is that only possible with 3rd party Windows FTP command-line clients as described by the link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/28832663/3208225](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28832663/3208225) ?

Comment: Find it hard to believe you can create a directory or rename a file but you cannot upload a file.  I don't know how a firewall could block some commands from FTP but not others.

Comment: Now I see the file is being created on FTP but empty. While on my local disk D it has simple word `Text` inside

Comment: As said by the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/48488685/3208225 _"one possibility is that the data-transfer connection is blocked by the firewall, whereas the control connection isn't"_

Comment: There's nothing you can configure in `ftp.exe` to make this working. So indeed, either setup the firewall or change your FTP client to some that supports passive mode.

Comment: My original question is not a fully duplicate since it contains two separate questions and the first of them about running cmd commands with WScript.Shell

Comment: Well, that's another problem. You cannot ask two separate questions in one post.

Comment: Ok. Btw, if I type `quote PASV` in ftp.exe, I get `227 Entering Passive Mode <...>`. Does it mean that ftp.exe of my Win7 has the passive mode?

Comment: No it does not mean anything. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28833096/850848

Comment: I've allowed ftp.exe checking both options for public and private networks in my Windows Firewall, but I still get the error 425 No data connection.

Comment: Try using `curl` instead of `ftp`.

`curl -u name:passwd ftp://yourdomain.com/full/path/to/file`

[Reference](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)