# Unable to store file using PHP cURL, timeout

Tags: php, php-curl, ftps

I'm stuck trying to upload a file to a FTPS server. I'm getting all the time a timeout error. The file is created on destination FTPS but it's always empty.
If I do use the same config on a FTP Server, it does work. Any thoughts what could be missing?
PHP 7.2 / cURL 7.67.
Here is a glimpse of the code :

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
$ftp_server = 'ftps://'.$server.':'.$port.'/'.$filename; 
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$username.':'.$passwd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //timeout in seconds

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl/7.67.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filename));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('curl.txt', 'w+'));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
$error_msg = curl_error($ch);
echo "<br> error_no: ".$error_no;
echo "<br> error msg :".$error_msg;
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

curl echo

```
error_no: 28
error msg :Operation timed out after 10003 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

curl.txt returns this...

```
...
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
* Request has same path as previous transfer
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||45592|).
*   Trying x.x.x.x:45592...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connecting to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 45592
* Connected to destination.address.dns (x.x.x.x) port 990 (#0)
> TYPE I
< 200 Type set to I
> STOR test.txt
* Operation timed out after 10010 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
```

Your advise would be very much appreciated.
D

Comment: Maybe look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700425/ftp-file-upload-doesnt-work-uploads-empty-files

Comment: @SScotti thanks for your reply. FYI, its works using FileZilla client. There must be a missing config item somewhere in my code. It does connect on passive mode but no data transfer. Any thoughts?

Comment: You are running the PHP code from a remote host ?  Is that running in a container or a VM ?  Also, here is another reference, but it does not use ftps apparently.  http://nlslack.com/ftp-access-using-curl-with-php/

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: See some mention of setting this, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV, to true also.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php  Good luck.

Comment: @shingo, file is 5 kb.

Comment: @SScotti EPSV is already set as you can see in the curl.txt log output. Adding it to the config didn't change anything. The script is ran from a VM. Are there any settings for the passive transfer that I should add maybe?

Comment: The reason I mentioned that was because of this:  https://superuser.com/questions/299496/curl-not-uploading-file-to-ftp/299515  Is it implicitly set or do you have to explicitly set it ?

Comment: @SScotti thanks for bringing this up. It's implicitly set to true. I've explicitly set to false and to true but result is the same

Comment: You may try a file < 1kb to see if succeeds.

Comment: @shingo same result. :(